Does this condition imply that a continuous surjection of manifolds is a fiber bundle?
Let $E$ and $B$ be topological manifolds of dimensions $n$ and $k$ with $k \leq n$. Denote the projection $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ onto the first $k$ coordinates by $\pi_{k \leftarrow n}$. Let $\pi: E \to B$ be a continuous surjection satisfying the following condition:

For any point $x \in E$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, an open neighbourhood $V$ of $\pi(x)$, an open set $\tilde{U}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and an open set $\tilde{V}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ as well as homeomorphisms $\varphi: U \to \tilde{U}$ and $\psi: V \to \tilde{V}$ such that the following diagram commutes:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @> \varphi >> \tilde{U} \\
@V \pi \big|_{V} VV @VV \pi_{k \leftarrow n} \big|_{\tilde{V}} V \\
V @>> \psi > \tilde{V} \\
\end{CD}
$$

Does this imply that $E \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} B$ is a fiber bundle?

Even if you assume everything is smooth, and that $\pi$ is a surjective submersion, the answer is still no. In fact if $\pi:E\to B$ is a surjective submersion between smooth manifolds, then the local submersion theorem (i.e a variant of the inverse/implicit function theorem) says exactly that this condition is satisfied.
But, we know that just because $\pi:E\to B$ is a surjective submersion, it does not follow that $(E,\pi,B)$ is a fiber bundle. For instance, consider the trivial fiber bundle $(\Bbb{R}^2,\text{pr}_1,\Bbb{R})$ and let $E$ be obtained by removing a single point $(x_0,y_0)$ from the total space, and let $\pi$ be the restriction of $\text{pr}_1$ to $E$. Then, $\pi:E\to\Bbb{R}$ is a smooth surjective submersion but is does not satisfy the local triviality (even in the continuous sense) because all the fibers are $\Bbb{R}$, except the fiber over $x_0$ is $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{y_0\}$ (and recall that when the base is connected, local triviality implies all the fibers are homeomorphic).
